# How can I use bind.FileVersion when harvesting using Heat?

Tags: wix, heat, wix3.8

I've previously used...

```
<?define PRODUCTVERSION="!(bind.FileVersion.MyLibrary.dll)" ?>
```

... to define a version variable for use in my installers. For the first time I'm using Heat.exe to harvest the files/folders I need in my installer (which includes MyLibrary.dll) to a file called Source.wxs.

If I try to build the installer I get the following error:

```
Unresolved bind-time variable !(bind.FileVersion.MyLibrary.dll)
```

It's like the Product.wxs file where the `PRODUCTVERSION` is declared can't see the Source.wxs file that has the details of the MyLibrary.dll, but I know this isn't true since if I set `PRODUCTVERSION="1.0.0.0"` then the installer builds and all this files are installed correctly.

How can I get `bind.FileVersion` to 'see' MyLibrary.dll?

**EDIT**

I can get it to work if I use the non-human friendly File Id from Source.wxs (see below), but is this really the best solution?

```
  <?define PRODUCTVERSION="!(bind.fileVersion.fil023E197261ED7268770DDE64994C4A55)" ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the output generated by Heat using XSL. That way you can transform the ID `fil023E197261ED7268770DDE64994C4A55` into something more readable which can be referenced in your project. To apply a transform to a `HeatDirectory` task you have to specify its `Transforms` attribute and set its value to a file name of an XSL file you have to create.

In that XSL file you'll have to manipulate the XML generated by heat. To rename the `Id` Attribute of the `File` element you can use the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

    <xsl:template match="//wix:File">
    <xsl:variable name="FilePath" select="@Source" />
    <xsl:variable name="FileName" select="substring-after($FilePath,'\')" />
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="Id">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="contains($FileName,'\')">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($FileName,'\')"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$FileName"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Read about XSL at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp) and check out the documentation of the [HeatDirectory task](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/task_reference/heatdirectory.html).

Answer (score 5):

It is much easier just to switch `SuppressUniqueIds` to `true`, you can see this in the [documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/task_reference/heatdirectory.html) as well.
As the result you will have a file name instead of a GUID in your Id.